# Issues forwarding ports after ISP IP Address change

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, ip-address, isp

My ISP recently (today) changed the dynamic IP address of my service, and has caused me some issues.

First off, I had to reset my static local IP, but got that taken care of. My router, model: WNR2000v4, auto changed the default gateway from 192.168.1.1 to 10.0.0.1, which is fine, I just had to change the IP address attached to each port that was forwarded.

However, now if I run a server with the open ports, I can no longer connect to them. I did refresh my IP on my machine as well as flush my DNS cache. I even went as far as to reset my firewall back to default settings and manually adding each service back to my exception list. I also disabled my firewall to check if it may be an issue, but no.

So far, everything I have done has been in vain. Do I just need to wait a while and try again later? Or should I contact my ISP to see what's up?

The ports I have open are

```
80 | TCP
3306 | TCP
25565 | UDP
27016 | UDP
```

80 and 3306 are my httpd/mysqld ports. The address is: 47.32.85.2

The page should display "Connected!" if you can load the web page from http://47.32.85.2

I'm completely out of ideas, and any suggestions would be appreciated. I'd love to get my Space Engineers server back up :p

Comment: You are exposing MySQL to the outside world?

Comment: I mean, if you wanna hack my database go ahead :p Nothing noteworthy in it. It's just on my local machine. Hasn't been touched. Besides, regarding my question, I can't seem to get any outside connections anyhow.

Comment: Well, unless something out on the internet needs to connect to it, I would avoid opening that port if it is not needed.

Comment: Understand. I'm not hosting mysql or web server from my computer as I have a VPN for that, but I had those forwarded to check TCP connections. And didn't feel like messing with config files to get a test open.

Comment: Ignoring that its insane to run MySQL on an unfirewalled port, it sounds like your ISP DID NOT only change your dynamic IP, rather they reconfigured your LAN.  I'd be jumping up and down if they did that to me - IMHO they have no business reconfiguring my equipment.   I'd also be getting another router and putting it behind theirs (double-nat be damned) to protect against this.

Comment: @davidgo I did put my firewall back up... I also reconfigured my LAN back to it's original settings with the default gateway and subnet mask that had been working for years now.

Comment: Are you sure you still have a public wan address and you're not already behind a double NAT?

Comment: Looking at the WAN settings on the router, NAT filtering is set to secure instead of open. But it's always been that way. Would that pose a problem? And if so, why hasn't it before?